# How to scan thousands of websites and analyze the changes each site's JavaScript makes to the page's DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

My task is:

Given a URL, parse its html page (easy), extract all javascripts (easy), and analyze what each javascript is doing/how DOM get changed by each javascript.

What I have tried:
various javascript engines - wont help, don't understand DOM
phantomjs/casperjs - the page.evaluateJavaScript API looks promising, but cannot get it to work, nowhere to find any document/examples

Any suggestion is highly appreciated. Thx.

Comment: Im not sure what you're asking..

Comment: So you are doing some kind of reverse engineering here?

Comment: A html page may contain many javascripts, the execution of each javascript block (starts with <script>, ends with </script>) may change DOM. What I'm asking is how can I know which part of DOM get changed/updated when a javascript block get executed.

Comment: If a DOM element is beinh changed by a block of code it should tell you in the code which element is being changed. Post some code and we will be able to point it out for you.

Comment: It's better if you write a brand new JS engine from scratch (any existing open source one won't help you, since their purpose is totally different) Even if you handle that with headless browsers such as zombie/casper/phantom e.g. you will need huge amounts of processing power for each website. Tip: It's easy to mimic spidermonkey so that you can provide a working DOM implementation to the target script blocks, here is good start point https://github.com/w3c/Amaya/blob/master/Amaya/amaya/javascript.c

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be looking for [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).  This is the methodology which permits you to register that your code is to be informed about changes the DOM.

It appears that you will need to set up a MutationObserver on every element for which you desire to know if it changes.  To do this, you will need to walk the DOM adding the MutationObservers to the elements.

In general, you should avoid using MutationObservers in most production code as they can significantly impact performance. However, it sounds like you want to specifically investigate the operation of some code, not use it in regular use. For that purpose, they should be fine.

- [A brief overview](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/02/Detect-DOM-changes-with-Mutation-Observers)
- [A more in-depth discussion](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/)
- [A screencast by Chromium developer Rafael Weinstein](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eRZ4pO0gVWw)
- [The mutation summary library](http://code.google.com/p/mutation-summary/)
- T[he DOM standard](http://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#mutation-observers) which defines the MutationObserver interface
- [Old Mutation events interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Mutation_events)

Example code:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    console.log(mutation.type);
  });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```

The list of additional reading and above code was taken from the [MutationObserver page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). That page lists the source of the example code as [this blog post](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/05/dom-mutationobserver-reacting-to-dom-changes-without-killing-browser-performance/).

### **EDIT 2:**

For such a large task as you described ("programmably scan thousands of websites") it might be easier for you to download the source code for Firefox and modify that code to make a record of the changes that each page's JavaScript makes to the page's DOM. This could very reasonably make a record of which section of code, which function, and even which line number within the source is making the change.

You want to "programmably scan thousands of websites".  That is not a small project and requires significant automation tools. Tools exist to automate browser actions (e.g. [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/)). Browsers already do *all* the work of interpreting JavaScript code and making changes to the DOM while knowing *exactly* which line/function of code is making the changes. Making minimal changes to publicly available source code to merely dump to the console that a change occurred, what line/function made the change, etc. is the *easy*  solution. The browser already dumps function/line to the console for JavaScript exceptions. All this requires is making minor changes to the source code to call the already existing function that dumps JavaScript function and line number to the console.  The console can be [redirected to store output in a file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.dump).

Comment: I did look into Mutation Observer, but it won't help in my case. I need to programmably scan thousands of websites (not my sites) and analyze some certain javascript block to see what DOM change they perform.

Comment: The only guaranteed method of finding out what changes they make to the DOM is watching the DOM and seeing what changes *actually are made*. It is possible for them to make changes via many different methods and the methods could be indirect.

Comment: Is it your desire to analyze only specific sections of code, or all of the sections of code on a site?

Comment: Modifying browser/js engine code will be my last resort if no existing software/technology can help.

Comment: Why is it your last resort?  It is the *easy* way. No need to have a new/different JS interpreter. All it has to do is dump JS function/line number when a change is made by the JS to the DOM. See more explanation in my answer.

Comment: If I have to go this route, I can foresee a major task will be making the browser headless by removing all GUI/displaying module due to the resource constraint. Doesn't sound like a trivial job.

Comment: **Please** provide a much more detailed description of your requirements and constraints *in the question* so we are not fumbling around providing you with answers which do not meet your needs. As part of that, please explain what requirements prevent the existence of a frame buffer (one that does not have a monitor attached, is targeted to a remote host for display, or even a virtual one).

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head there are several ways to look at a block of JavaScript code and find out which element is being changed.

```
// Single Element
    var elementById = document.getElementById("elementID"); // Reference by ID
    var elementByClass = document.getElementByClass("elementClass"); // Reference by Class
    var elementByTag = document.getElementByTagName("elementTag"); // Reference by Tag Name

// Multipe Element
    var elementsByClass = document.getElementsByClassName("elementsClass"); // Reference by Class
    var elementsByTag = document.getElementsByTagName("elementsTag"); // Reference by Tag
```

If you need further assistance please be more direct with your question.